# PSA: Adding these tags

Tags: discussion, tags

This post is a response to [Can we formulate a response to the large number of kids under 13?](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2375/can-we-formulate-a-response-to-the-large-number-of-kids-under-13):

---

I am going to go add these tags:

- [rape](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rape)
- [torture](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torture)

I see that these tags have already been added:

- [profanity](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/profanity)
- [erotica](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/erotica)

This way younger users and people who would prefer avoiding these topics (like me) can block the tags.

Is it okay that editing past, relevant questions to add these tags will bump them to the top of the homepage?

Anyway, this is a PSA to let y'all know what I plan to be doing over the coming days.

[image]

---

credit: giphy.com for the image

---

Update: I started a wave of edits to add in [torture](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torture) and [rape](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rape) in to relevant questions. Sorry for messing up the home page! I'll try and get it done fast so we can put this behind us.

I also created tag descriptions for the tags [torture](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torture) and [rape](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rape).

---

Second update:

The tags [torture](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torture) and [sexual-assault](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexual-assault) have been added and have descriptions. I will slowly edit them into questions.

### **Huge** thanks to linksassin for making these tags possible and correcting some of my incorrect edits. Couldn't have done it without him.

Comment: FYI When making large changes like this it is generally better to wait a day or two after the announcement just in case there is disagreement, not that I'm expecting it here. Also as a curtesy, making them in small batches (6-10 per day) you can prevent it from flooding the homepage. Thats better than trying to get it all done at once.

Comment: @linksassin Thanks for the heads up! Sorry for the small wait time, I am a pretty impatient person - once I get my mindset on something I tend to get in fixated on it until I see it through.

Comment: (which is something I am trying to change about me...)

Comment: No stress, it's just something to get used to on an international site. Timezones wizardry and whatnot means you often need to wait 24 hours to ensure anyone that wants to might have a chance to see things.

Comment: I'm just reviewing some of your edits and you appear to have added the rape/sexual-assault tag to a few questions that don't actual reference anything like that. We have the [tag:erotica] and [tag:sex] tags for depictions of consensual sex-scene. Just try to use the correct tag.

Comment: @linksassin *Wow* did I mess up some of those tag edits :( --- Major thanks to you, I owe you big time for your guidance and help on these issues.

Comment: Not a problem. This is part of our role as mods and experience users. As you learn more you find opportunities to teach newer users, its part of the site model and I find it pretty rewarding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Assessing if tags are useful

A while ago Secespitus created a [useful list of questions](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1498/33442) to consider when creating tags:

> 1. Ask yourself how many questions you have about this topic: is this probably the only one or is this a topic you want to ask about more regularly?
> 2. Look through the existing questions: how many already use the word or similar words and might profit from the tag?
> 3. Look through the existing tags: is one of them already encompassing what you are trying to convey?
> 4. Look through Meta: have there been similar requests or precedent cases where something similar has been created/denied?
> 5. Think about the sites scope: do you think that a lot of people will profit from these tags when they are asking questions about the specific topic of the site you are on?
> 6. Think about the tag's scope: is it well-defined and obvious to users coming to the site?

For each of the tags you are creating it might be worth going through this list.

---

#### The [rape](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rape) tag

1. You have said that you will be blocking the tag so unlikely that you will ask more questions on it. However others likely will. - **+0**
2. Many questions already exist where this tag could be used. - **+1**
3. It doesn't look like we have a tag that covers the questions you are looking at with this tag. - **+1**
4. The closest we have is [this meta](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/788/33442) so you are fine here. - **+1**
5. You have already address this in your question. There is a clear benefit here. - **+1**
6. The scope of the question is clear, but I think it could use some refinement. - **+0**

In summary you have 4 point in favour a tag and none against so it seems a tag for these question would be useful. However, I think we can improve the tag with a little thought.

I would prefer the main tag to be [sexual-assault](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexual-assault) with [rape](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rape) as a synonym, to reduce the impact of triggers. Also to include some relevant trigger warning guidance in the tag wiki. This would catch a broader set of questions but also improve it's usage.

#### The [torture](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torture) tag

1. Again, you are unlikely to be asking questions on this topic, but others will. - **+0**
2. You've already found a few, and there's likely to be more if you widen your search terms. - **+1**
3. Existing tags, [combat](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combat) [horror](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror) [pain](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pain) don't quite cover the same niche as your proposed tag. - **+1**
4. I couldn't find anything similar on meta. - **+1**
5. Both as a trigger warning and a sorting method for those writing scenes like this, I believe this tag is useful. - **+1**
6. The scope is fairly well defined and relatively self-evident. - **+1**

This tag has 5 points for an none against. With a good tag except and wiki I don't see any reason not to go ahead with the creation of this tag.

#### The [porn](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/porn) tag

1. You won't use it, and based on the question you have added it to I'm not sure other will either. - **-1**
2. There are a handful of existing questions on this topic. - **+1**
3. Here is your real problem. I don't see what this tag adds that is not covered by the tags [erotica](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/erotica) for the genre and [sex](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) for scene depictions. - **-1**
4. We have [this meta](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/788/33442) about creating the erotica and sex tags. - **-1**
5. I don't see much benefit to the site for this tag. Writers already have the tags mentioned above, and anyone else trying to use it to search would find what they are looking for to be extremely off-topic here. - **-1**
6. I don't see this as well defined. You have used it on question containing the word 'porn' but are about both sexual and violence. For mean this tag is unclear is its purpose. - **-1**

Overall I see 5 points against, and only 1 in favour of this tag. Perhaps it would have a better chance as a synonym of [erotica](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/erotica). But I don't think this tag adds much value and should probably not be added.

Comment: Thanks for the very informative answer! Since the tags rape and torture seem fine to add (with the possible change from rape to sexual assault) we can keep them (feel free to edit their descriptions). Is it possible to destroy the porn tag since it seems worthless now in perspective? Again, thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: @Nai45 If a tag is removed from all questions, it will get auto-destroyed in a day or so. But yes, you can go ahead with adding the [tag:sexual-assault] and [tag:torture] tags to appropriate questions at a reasonable rate as to not flood the frontpage.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically rename the now created tag [rape] to [sexual assault] without going through and manually switching them?

Comment: @Nai45 Yes, we can create a [tag synonym](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) which will automatically rename the tags when edited. I've actually just gone ahead and done this.